# React/Tailwind Shrinking Window Forces Page on top of Another Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Utilizing ReactJS and TailwindCSS, when I display the webpage within the standard fullscreen mode, everything is formatted correctly, however, when I shrink the window to see how the pages adjust for mobile/smaller screens, my last page contents end up being displayed over the second to last page's.

EDIT: Single page application.

Here's what is displayed when the window is condensed to a mobile format
[image: Mobile Format Window]

And here is what the full screen window depicts; what it actually is supposed to look like, as it is rendered on its own page.
[image: Full screen window]

Here is the code for both pages:

Page 1, the second to last page that the last page is displaying on top of when the window is condensed.

```
<div name="experience" className="bg-slate-50 h-screen dark:bg-[#222222] transition ease-out duration-500">
        <div className="max-w-[1000px] mx-auto p-4 flex flex-col justify-content w-full h-full">
            <div className='dark:text-gray-200'>
                <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline border-b-4 border-[#6e5fff]">Experience</p>
                <p className="text-lg italic font-mono py-5 text-green-800 dark:text-[#23b347]">// Here, you can list what tools you're familiar with</p>
            </div>
        

            <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-6 gap-4 text-center my-[-10px]">
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.html} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">HTML</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.css} alt="CSS icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">CSS</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.react} alt="React icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">ReactJS/Native</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.flutter} alt="flutter icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Flutter</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.redux} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Redux</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.vue} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Vue</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.cs} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">C#</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.cpp} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">C++</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.python} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Python</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.sass} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Sass</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-4" src={images.bootstrap} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="font-bold">Bootstrap</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.javascript} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Javascript</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.mongo} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">MongoDB</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.firebase} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Firebase</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-[70px] mx-auto my-4" src={images.typescript} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">TypeScript</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.django} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Django</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.git} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Git</p>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-20 mx-auto my-1" src={images.photoshop} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Photoshop</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="inline my-[15px]">
                <p className="text-lg flex font-mono italic text-green-800 dark:text-[#23b347]">// Work related positions</p>
            </div>
            <div className="max-w-[1000px] p-3 my-[-10px] w-full grid grid-cols-2 gap-1 text-center">
                <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 dark:text-gray-300 hover:dark:text-black w-[45%] h-[90%] rounded-lg dark:bg-[#353535] hover:scale-110 duration-500 hover:bg-[#aaa0ff] hover:dark:bg-[#aaa0ff] transition ease-out">
                    <img className="w-[70%] mx-auto py-20 sm:py-0 my-1" src={images.companyLOGO} alt="HTML icon" />
                    <p className="my-4 font-bold">Name of your company</p>
                </div>
                <div className="max-w-[1000px] w-full justify-items-start flex-col sm:text-left text-left mx-[-45%] my-[-5px]">
                    <div>
                        <p className="my-9 text-xl font-bold dark:text-gray-300 border-b-2 border-gray-300 dark:border-[#313131] inline">Position Held</p>
                        <p className="my-1 dark:text-gray-400">List your responsibilities here, make sure to contain this entire area for maximum effect. </p>
                        <p className="my-1 dark:text-gray-400">Here you can list certain actions or achievements you obtained within the position:
                            <br />- list 1
                            <br />- list 2
                            <br />- list 3
                            <br />- list 4
                        </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the last page, the one that displays on top of the second to last when said window condenses.

```
return (
    <div name="contact" className="h-screen bg-slate-50 dark:bg-[#222222] transition ease-out duration-500">
        <div className="w-full h-full max-w-[1000px] mx-auto flex justify-center items-center p-4 flex-col">
            <form method="POST" action="link" className="flex flex-col max-w-[600px] w-full">
                <div className="pb-4 flex items-center">
                    <p className="text-4xl font-bold inline dark:text-gray-200 border-[#6e5fff]">Contact 
                    <span className="text-[#6e5fff]"> Me</span>
                    </p>
                    {/* <p className="px-5 h-5 py-5">// Email me </p> */}
                    <div className="shadow-lg bg-gray-200 dark:bg-[#353535] dark:text-gray-300 rounded-lg flex flex-row items-center mx-5 px-4 py-1 justify-self-end">
                        <FiMail style={{ marginRight: 5, color: '#6e5fff' }}/>
                        <p>your email here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex pb-3">
                    <p className="text-green-800 dark:text-[#23b347] font-mono">// or fill out the form below:</p>
                </div>
                <input type="text" className="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-[#353535] dark:border-[#2c2c2c] shadow-md rounded-xl p-2" placeholder='Your Name' name='name'/>
                <input type="email" className="my-4 bg-gray-200 dark:bg-[#353535] dark:border-[#2c2c2c] shadow-md rounded-xl p-2" placeholder='Your Email' name='email'/>
                <textarea className="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-[#353535] dark:border-[#2c2c2c] p-2 rounded-xl shadow-md" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div className="justify-center flex">
                    <button className='text-white px-6 w-[26%] group py-4 my-5 rounded-xl bg-[#6e5fff] flex items-center hover:bg-[#9c92ff] transition ease-out duration-500' >Reach Out
                        <span className='group-hover:animate-bounce'>
                            <FiSend className='ml-2'/>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div className="justify-center flex flex-row gap-[350px]">
                <button className='justify-self-auto'>
                    <FaLinkedin className='dark:bg-gray-200' onClick={event =>  window.open(linkedIn)} style={{ color: "#0e76a8", width: 40, height: 40,}} />
                </button>
                <button className='justify-self-auto '>
                    <FaGithub className='dark:fill-gray-200' style={{ color: "black", width: 40, height: 40,}} />
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
```

This is my first time utilizing TailwindCSS with ReactJS, so I'm assuming I've just left out one section of formatting/padding, at least that is what I'm hoping for.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are both of these components rendering at the same time?

Comment: Its a single-page application, not multi-page, so the entirety of each file is loaded at once?

Comment: Even if they're on the same page, you can still find a way to only conditionally render one of these components at a time.

Comment: That's what I've been searching for really, and I haven't come across any documentation that dictates it yet (at least in the capacity that is required); maybe I'm not looking through the correct docs.

Comment: Can you share some of the logic that determines which components (experience, contact, etc.) are rendered?

Comment: Ended up fixing it, turned out to be a padding issue, not a render issue, as one of the y-axis paddings was set to 20 instead of 2.